# Is there any way to work with NetCDF files in Nim?

Tags: data-science, netcdf, nim-lang

I've discovered Nim some days ago and am really interested in it.
However, I need to know if I'd able to work with NetCDF files (or at least GRB files) to see if it is suitable for my every-day life.
I've searched the web for some library or code, but couldn't find any, so if anybody knows a way to do it, please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possible options (as of September 2020) to work with netcdf files using nim:

- since netcdf4 is based on hdf5, maybe [nimhdf5](https://github.com/Vindaar/nimhdf5) could be useful
- using [nimpy](https://github.com/yglukhov/nimpy) bridge to access python libraries that access netcdf, such as [netcdf4-python](https://github.com/Unidata/netcdf4-python) (your local python environment will be a dependency)
- wrap [netcdf C api](https://github.com/Unidata/netcdf-c) using tools like [c2nim](https://github.com/nim-lang/c2nim) or [nimterop](https://github.com/nimterop/nimterop)